# How to install snowflake cli on AIX Machine

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I see there is documentation on how to download and install snowsql client on a linux machine. Are these steps same for AIX machine ?

Comment: You could as well add the URL of the said documentation.

Comment: Did you try .. It should be same for any other Linux Distro .  You just need to download and bash the snowsql script.